# JUnit5 parameterized tests at class level

Tags: java, kotlin, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

Is it possible to use JUnit5's parameterized new features to run test classes to receive test parameters instead of doing it at method level?

With JUnit 4 a runner such as `@RunWith(Parameterized::class)` plus inheritance could be used to pass an array of parameters to subclasses, but I am not sure if it is possible to achieve something equivalent but using the new JUnit 5 api.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878

Comment: @mkobit Exactly. Are there any alternatives for that?

Comment: There may be a workaround, it would be useful to sample code about what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: Similar popular question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897134/how-to-implement-junit-4-parameterized-tests-in-junit-5

Answer (score 24):

Short answer
there's no way to parametrize *class creation* with **JUnit 5** following the style of **JUnit 4**.

Fortunately, the very intention of separation test logic and test input data (parameters) can be implemented differently.

---

**JUnit 5** has its own approach for making parameterized tests, and, of course, it is different from **JUnit 4**. The new approach does not allow to use parameterized fixtures at the class level, i.e. through its every test method.
So every parameterized test method should be explicitly annotated with a *link to parameters*.

**JUnit 5** provides a plenty of parameter source types, that could be found in [documentation](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) and [guides](https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2018/12/30/Junit-5-Write-Powerful-Unit-Test-Cases-Using-Parameterized-Tests)

In your case, the simplest way to migrate from `@Parameters` of **Junit 4** is using `@MethodSource` or `@ArgumentsSource` of `org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.*`.

**JUnit 4**:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestWithJunit4 {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
               { 0, 0, 0 },
               { 1, 2, 3 }, 
               { 5, 3, 8 } 
      });
    }

    int first;
    int second;
    int sum;

    public MyTestWithJunit4(int first, int second, int sum) {
      this.first = first;
      this.second = second;
      this.sum = sum;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
      assertEquals(sum, first + second));
    }
}
```

**JUnit 5 (with `@MethodSource`)**:

```
class MyTestWithJunit5 {

  @DisplayName("Test with @MethodSource")
  @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}: ({0} + {1}) => {2})")
  @MethodSource("localParameters")
  void test(int first, int second, int sum) {
    assertEquals(sum, first + second);
  }

  static Stream<Arguments> localParameters() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(0, 0, 0),
        Arguments.of(1, 2, 3),
        Arguments.of(5, 3, 8)
    );
  }
}
```

**JUnit 5 (with `@ArgumentsSource`)**:

```
class MyTestWithJunit5 {
  @DisplayName("Test with @ArgumentsSource")
  @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}: ({0} + {1}) => {2})")
  @ArgumentsSource(Params.class)
  void test(int first, int second, int sum) {
    assertEquals(sum, first + second);
  }

  static class Params implements ArgumentsProvider {
    @Override
    public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
      return Stream.of(
          Arguments.of(0, 0, 0),
          Arguments.of(1, 2, 3),
          Arguments.of(5, 3, 8)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Consider that a method in `@MethodSource` and a class in `@ArgumentsSource` could be described anywhere, not only inside the same class where the test methods are located. Also `@MethodSource` allows to provide multiple source methods, since its `value` is a `String[]`.

**Some remarks and comparison**

In **JUnit 4** we could only have a single factory method providing parameters, and the tests were supposed to be built around those parameters.
On the contrary, **JUnit 5** gives more abstraction and flexibility in binding parameters and decouples test logic from its parameters, which are secondary.
That allows building tests independently from parameter sources, and easily change them when needed.

**Dependency requirement**

Parameterized tests feature is not included in the core `junit-jupiter-engine`,
but is located in a separate dependency [`junit-jupiter-params`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params).

Comment: Seems to be a serious lack in Junit 5.  We have `Nested` now to test entire flows with short to the point test methods, but no way to initialize those flows with different parameters.

Comment: This is an awesome summary of what can be done but this doesn't stress enough the sad fact (and the actual answer to the question) that there's no way to parametrize class creation in Junit 5 (and was possible in Junit 4.

Answer (score 10):

Create a meta annotation that specifies the parameterisation, and apply it to the test methods:

```java
public class MyTest {
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0}")
    @MethodSource("allImplementations")
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    private @interface TestAllImplementations {
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> allImplementations() {
        return Stream.of(
             Arguments.of("Serial", new SerialWidget()),
             Arguments.of("Concurrent", new ConcurrentWidget())
        );
    }

    @TestAllImplementations
    void myFirstTest(String name, Widget implementation) {
        /* ... */
    }

    @TestAllImplementations
    void mySecondTest(String name, Widget implementation) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I could find was to make the old test abstract.
Then create a new class that has nested tests for each variation eg.

```
public class NewParametricTest {
  @Nested
  public class NewParametricTestVariation1Test
    extends AbstractOriginalToBeParameticizedTest {
    public NewParametricTestVariation1Test() {
      super("Some parameter", 1);
    }
  }

  // add others here
}
```

Comment: Amazing! This saved my day! Thank you! :)

Comment: @domin feel free to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ParameterizedTest()
@MethodSource("dataProvider")
void testWithDataProvider(String str, List<JSONObject> list) {
    System.out.println();

}

static Stream<Arguments> dataProvider() {
    String json = """
            {
                "test":1 
            }
                    """;
    return Stream.of(
            arguments("abc", Arrays.asList(new JSONObject(json))),
            arguments("lemon", Arrays.asList(new JSONObject(json)))
    );
```

I bypassed this complexity in this way