# How to implement JUnit 4 parameterized tests in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit5

In JUnit 4 it was easy to test invariants across a bunch of classes by using the [`@Parameterized`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) annotation. The key thing is that a collection of tests are being run against a single list of arguments.

How to replicate this in JUnit 5, without using JUnit-vintage?

[`@ParameterizedTest`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) is not applicable to a test class. [`@TestTemplate`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-templates) sounded like it might be appropriate, but that annotation's target is also a method.

---

An example of such a JUnit 4 test is:

```
@RunWith( Parameterized.class )
public class FooInvariantsTest{

   @Parameterized.Parameters
   public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
       return new Arrays.asList(
               new Object[]{ new CsvFoo() ),
               new Object[]{ new SqlFoo() ),
               new Object[]{ new XmlFoo() ),
           );
   }

   private Foo fooUnderTest;


   public FooInvariantsTest( Foo fooToTest ){
        fooUnderTest = fooToTest;
   }

   @Test
   public void testInvariant1(){
       ...
   }

   @Test
   public void testInvariant2(){
       ...
   } 
}
```

Comment: For completeness, there is already an issue for this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The parameterized test feature in JUnit 5 doesn't provide the exact same features than those provided by JUnit 4.
New features with more flexibility were introduced... but it also lost the  JUnit4 feature where the parameterized test class uses the parameterized fixtures/assertions at the class level that is for all test methods of the class.
Defining `@ParameterizedTest` for each test method by specifying the "input" is so needed.
Beyond that lack I will present the main differences between the 2 versions and how to use parameterized tests in JUnit 5.

**TL;DR**

To write a parameterized test that specifies a value by case to test as your in your question,
 [`org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) should do the job.

> `@MethodSource` allows you to refer to one or more methods of the test
>   class. Each method must return a `Stream`, `Iterable`, `Iterator`, or array
>   of arguments. In addition, each method must not accept any arguments.
>   By default such methods must be static unless the test class is
>   annotated with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`.
>
> If you only need a single parameter, you can return instances of the
>   parameter type directly as demonstrated by the following example.

As JUnit 4, `@MethodSource` relies on a factory method and may also be used for test methods that specify multiple arguments.

**In JUnit 5, it is the way of writing parameterized tests the closest to JUnit 4.**

JUnit 4 :

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
```

JUnit 5 :

```
private static Stream<Arguments> data() {
```

Main improvements :

- `Collection<Object[]>` is become `Stream<Arguments>` that provides more flexibility.
- the way of binding the factory method to the test method differs a little.
  It is now shorter and less error prone : no more requirement to create a constructor and declares field to set the value of each parameter. The binding of the source is done directly on the parameters of the test method.
- With JUnit 4, inside a same class, one and only one factory method has to be declared with `@Parameters`.
  With JUnit 5, this limitation is lifted : multiple methods may indeed be used as factory method. 
  So, inside the class, we can so declare some test methods annotated with `@MethodSource("..")` that refer different factory methods.

For example here is a sample test class that asserts some addition computations :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

public class ParameterizedMethodSourceWithArgumentsTest {

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("addFixture")
  void add(int a, int b, int result) {
     Assertions.assertEquals(result, a + b);
  }

  private static Stream<Arguments> addFixture() {
    return Stream.of(
      Arguments.of(1, 2, 3),
      Arguments.of(4, -4, 0),
      Arguments.of(-3, -3, -6));
  }
}
```

To upgrade existing parameterized tests from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, `@MethodSource` is a candidate to consider.

---

**Summarize**

`@MethodSource` has some strengths but also some weaknesses.
New ways to specify sources of the parameterized tests were introduced in JUnit 5.
Here some additional information (far being exhaustive) about them that I hope could give a broad idea on how deal with in a general way.

**Introduction**

JUnit 5 introduces [parameterized tests feature](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) in these terms :

> Parameterized tests make it possible to run a test multiple times with
>   different arguments. They are declared just like regular `@Test` methods
>   but use the `@ParameterizedTest` annotation instead. In addition, you
>   must declare at least one source that will provide the arguments for
>   each invocation.

**Dependency requirement**

Parameterized tests feature is not included in the `junit-jupiter-engine` core dependency.
You should add a specific dependency to use it : `junit-jupiter-params`.

If you use Maven, this is the dependency to declare :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Sources available to create data**

Contrary to JUnit 4, JUnit 5 provides multiple flavors and artifacts to write parameterized tests 
The ways to favor depend generally on the source of data you want to use.

Here are the source types proposed by the framework and described in the [documentation](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) :

- `@ValueSource`
- `@EnumSource`
- `@MethodSource`
- `@CsvSource`
- `@CsvFileSource`
- `@ArgumentsSource`

Here are the 3 main sources I actually use with JUnit 5 and I will present:

- `@MethodSource`
- `@ValueSource`
- `@CsvSource`

I consider them as basic as I write parameterized tests. They should allow to write in JUnit 5, the type of JUnit 4 tests that you described.
`@EnumSource`, `@ArgumentsSource` and `@CsvFileSource`  may of course be helpful but they are more specialized.

**Presentation of `@MethodSource`, `@ValueSource` and `@CsvSource`**

1) `@MethodSource`

This type of source requires to define a factory method.
But it also provides much flexibility.

**In JUnit 5, it is the way of writing parameterized tests the closest to JUnit 4.**

If you have a **single method parameter** in the test method and you want to use **any type** as source,  `@MethodSource` is a very good candidate.
To achieve it, define a method that returns a Stream of the value for each case and annotate the test method with `@MethodSource("methodName")` where `methodName` is the name of this data source method.

For example, you could write :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

public class ParameterizedMethodSourceTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getValue_is_never_null_fixture")
    void getValue_is_never_null(Foo foo) {
       Assertions.assertNotNull(foo.getValue());
    }

    private static Stream<Foo> getValue_is_never_null_fixture() {
       return Stream.of(new CsvFoo(), new SqlFoo(), new XmlFoo());
    }

}
```

If you have **multiple method parameters** in the test method and you want to use **any type** as source,  `@MethodSource` is also a very good candidate.
To achieve it, define a method that returns a Stream of `org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments` for each case to test.

For example, you could write :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

public class ParameterizedMethodSourceWithArgumentsTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getFormatFixture")
    void getFormat(Foo foo, String extension) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(extension, foo.getExtension());
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> getFormatFixture() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(new SqlFoo(), ".sql"),
        Arguments.of(new CsvFoo(), ".csv"),
        Arguments.of(new XmlFoo(), ".xml"));
    }
}
```

2)`@ValueSource`

If you have a **single method parameter** in the test method and you may represent the source of the parameter from **one of these built-in types (String, int, long, double)**,  `@ValueSource` suits.

`@ValueSource` defines indeed these attributes :

```
String[] strings() default {};
int[] ints() default {};
long[] longs() default {};
double[] doubles() default {};
```

You could for example use it in this way :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

public class ParameterizedValueSourceTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = { 1, 2, 3 })
    void sillyTestWithValueSource(int argument) {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(argument);
    }

}
```

Beware 1) you must not specify more than one annotation attribute. 
Beware 2) The mapping between the source and the parameter of the method can be done between two distinct types. 
The type `String` used as source of data allows particularly, thanks to its parsing, to be converted into multiple other types.

3) `@CsvSource`

If you have  **multiple method parameters** in the test method, a `@CsvSource` may suit.
To use it, annotate the test with `@CsvSource` and specify in a array of `String` each case.
Values of each case are separated by a comma.

Like `@ValueSource`, the mapping between the source and the parameter of the method can be done between two distinct types. 
Here is an example that illustrates that :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

public class ParameterizedCsvSourceTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({ "12,3,4", "12,2,6" })
    public void divideTest(int n, int d, int q) {
       Assertions.assertEquals(q, n / d);
    }

}
```

**`@CsvSource` VS  `@MethodSource`**

These source types serve a very classic requirement : mapping from the source to **multiple method parameters** in the test method.
But their approach is different.

`@CsvSource` has some advantages : it is clearer and shorter.
Indeed, parameters are defined just above the tested method, no requirement to create a fixture method that may in addition generate "unused" warnings.
But it also has an important limitation concerning mapping types.
You have to provide an array of `String`. The framework provides conversion features but it is limited.

To summarize, while the `String` provided as source and the parameters of the test method have the same type (`String`->`String`) or rely on built-in conversion (`String`->`int` for example), `@CsvSource` appears as the way to use.

As it is not the case, you have to make a choice between 
keeping the flexibility of `@CsvSource` by creating a custom converter (`ArgumentConverter` subclass) for conversions not performed by the framework **or** using `@MethodSource` with a factory method that 
returns `Stream<Arguments>`.
 It has the drawbacks described above but it also has the great benefit to map out-of-the box any type from the source to the parameters.

**Argument Conversion**

About the mapping between the source (`@CsvSource` or `@ValueSource` for example) and the parameters of the test method, as seen, the framework allows to do some conversions if the types are not the same.

[Here](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-argument-conversion) is a presentation of the two types of conversions :

> **3.13.3. Argument Conversion**
>
> **Implicit Conversion**
>
> To support use cases like `@CsvSource`, JUnit Jupiter provides a number
>   of built-in implicit type converters. The conversion process depends
>   on the declared type of each method parameter.
>
> .....
>
> `String` instances are currently implicitly converted to the following
>   target types.
>
> ```
> Target Type          |  Example
> boolean/Boolean      |  "true" → true
> byte/Byte            |  "1" → (byte) 1
> char/Character       |  "o" → 'o'
> short/Short          |  "1" → (short) 1
> int/Integer          |  "1" → 1
> .....
> ```

For example in the previous example, an implicit conversion is done between `String` from source and `int` defined as parameter:

```
@CsvSource({ "12,3,4", "12,2,6" })
public void divideTest(int n, int d, int q) {
   Assertions.assertEquals(q, n / d);
}
```

And here, an implicit conversion is done from `String` source to `LocalDate` parameter:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-03-01" })
void testWithValueSource(LocalDate date) {
    Assertions.assertTrue(date.getYear() == 2018);
}
```

If for two types, no conversion is provided by the framework,
which is the case for custom types, you should use an `ArgumentConverter`.

> **Explicit Conversion**
>
> Instead of using implicit argument conversion you may explicitly
>   specify an `ArgumentConverter` to use for a certain parameter using the
>   `@ConvertWith` annotation like in the following example.

JUnit provides a reference implementation for clients who need to create a specific `ArgumentConverter`.

> Explicit argument converters are meant to be implemented by test
>   authors. Thus, junit-jupiter-params only provides a single explicit
>   argument converter that may also serve as a reference implementation:
>   `JavaTimeArgumentConverter`. It is used via the composed annotation
>   `JavaTimeConversionPattern`.

Test method using this converter :

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { "01.01.2017", "31.12.2017" })
void testWithExplicitJavaTimeConverter(@JavaTimeConversionPattern("dd.MM.yyyy") LocalDate argument) {
    assertEquals(2017, argument.getYear());
}
```

`JavaTimeArgumentConverter` converter class :

```
package org.junit.jupiter.params.converter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetTime;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.jupiter.params.support.AnnotationConsumer;

/**
 * @since 5.0
 */
class JavaTimeArgumentConverter extends SimpleArgumentConverter
        implements AnnotationConsumer<JavaTimeConversionPattern> {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, TemporalQuery<?>> TEMPORAL_QUERIES;
    static {
        Map<Class<?>, TemporalQuery<?>> queries = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        queries.put(ChronoLocalDate.class, ChronoLocalDate::from);
        queries.put(ChronoLocalDateTime.class, ChronoLocalDateTime::from);
        queries.put(ChronoZonedDateTime.class, ChronoZonedDateTime::from);
        queries.put(LocalDate.class, LocalDate::from);
        queries.put(LocalDateTime.class, LocalDateTime::from);
        queries.put(LocalTime.class, LocalTime::from);
        queries.put(OffsetDateTime.class, OffsetDateTime::from);
        queries.put(OffsetTime.class, OffsetTime::from);
        queries.put(Year.class, Year::from);
        queries.put(YearMonth.class, YearMonth::from);
        queries.put(ZonedDateTime.class, ZonedDateTime::from);
        TEMPORAL_QUERIES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(queries);
    }

    private String pattern;

    @Override
    public void accept(JavaTimeConversionPattern annotation) {
        pattern = annotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object input, Class<?> targetClass) throws ArgumentConversionException {
        if (!TEMPORAL_QUERIES.containsKey(targetClass)) {
            throw new ArgumentConversionException("Cannot convert to " + targetClass.getName() + ": " + input);
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        TemporalQuery<?> temporalQuery = TEMPORAL_QUERIES.get(targetClass);
        return formatter.parse(input.toString(), temporalQuery);
    }

}
```

Comment: Small point about `@MethodSource` - it can also work for multiple arguments and a lot of use cases by using [`org.junit.jupiter.params.provider`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/Arguments.html). For example, something like `Stream.of(Arguments.of(5, "stringValue", myOwnType))` will work for an `@Test` like `methodSig(int arg1, String arg2, MyOwnType arg3)`.

Comment: @mkobit  You are totally right. It is an important point. Thank you. I also use it. I updated.

Comment: So, I need to mark each individual test case as `@ParameterizedTest` and each one will need to take the parameters in the method declaration, and there is no way around it?

Comment: @ArtB at the moment, mostly yes. You could also define a meta-annotation or a lightweight extension that does what you want it to do. You should comment and follow on [junit5#878](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878) on your how you might expect to use it (if that is indeed the correct use case for what you are asking for).

Comment: @mkobit Thanks, that's kinda all the answer I needed.

Comment: One argument in favour of junit 4 parameterized tests support is the @Before/@After methods. Because the test parameters are passed to Test class constructor in the @Before/@After we can do some operations (test fixtures) with passed parameter before the test method is called. I don't even figure out how to do this in junit 5. I suppose `TestTemplate` would be useful in this case, probably.