# JUnit 5 and multiple input data (Java)

Tags: java, junit, parameterized, parameterized-unit-test

How to use JUnit 5 to run series of tests of a computation, each  for a different pair of input data and benchmark output?

Condition: the computation should be performed only once per input and not for every test separately as it is time-intensive.

Every test checks a number put out by the already imperfectly written computation module. It is not feasible to restructure the module into separately testable subfunctions.

Comment: `DataModelTest.readModel(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' could not be resolved` -- The class name is `ModelTest`, not `DataModelTest`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897134/how-to-implement-junit-4-parameterized-tests-in-junit-5 (@davidxxx's excellent answer)

You appear to be misusing the @MethodSource annotation, i.e. "method must not accept any arguments".

Comment: @geneSummons - that solution is the standard in which the arguments are all read just by a test method. I would like to have a function that could read the arguments and feed the test methods with precomputed values - such as a constructor of the test class that would have them as an attribute. But this seems to be forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution is to

1. Read all data and perform all computations in the constructor, saving the outputs as an array/list and doing the same with benchmark outputs.
2. Call @ParameterizedTests with @ValueSource taking an array of integers. They will iterate over the lists stored as object attributes using these integers as indices.