# JUnit5 - can I parameterize execution of entire test class?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, parameterized, parameterized-unit-test

Starting from the following generic code, showing a sample test class that needs to be executed for several rounds of input data:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class DummyManyTests {

    @BeforeAll
    public void beforeAll() {
        log.info("before all...");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public void afterAll() {
        log.info("after all...");
    }

    static Stream<Integer> countParameterProvider() {
        return Stream.of(50, 100, 200);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("countParameterProvider")
    @Order(10)
    public void m1(int count) {
        log.info("m1 #count: {}", count);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("countParameterProvider")
    @Order(20)
    public void m2(int count) {
        log.info("m2 #count: {}", count);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("countParameterProvider")
    @Order(30)
    public void m3(int count) {
        log.info("m3 #count: {}", count);
    }

}
```

Which generates this output:

```
15:38:54.878 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - before all...
15:38:54.973 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m1 #count: 50
15:38:55.004 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m1 #count: 100
15:38:55.007 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m1 #count: 200
15:38:55.013 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m2 #count: 50
15:38:55.015 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m2 #count: 100
15:38:55.018 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m2 #count: 200
15:38:55.021 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m3 #count: 50
15:38:55.025 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m3 #count: 100
15:38:55.028 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m3 #count: 200
15:38:55.030 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - after all...
```

I need to change the way the tests are parameterized.
**Basically I need to have the entire entire class executed end-to-end (including `beforeAll` and `afterAll`)**, *for each value of that parameter*.

The output would then become:

```
15:38:54.878 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - before all...
15:38:54.973 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m1 #count: 50
15:38:55.013 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m2 #count: 50
15:38:55.021 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m3 #count: 50
15:38:55.030 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - after all...
15:38:54.878 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - before all...
15:38:55.004 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m1 #count: 100
15:38:55.015 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m2 #count: 100
15:38:55.025 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m3 #count: 100
15:38:55.030 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - after all...
15:38:54.878 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - before all...
15:38:55.007 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m1 #count: 200
15:38:55.018 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m2 #count: 200
15:38:55.028 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - m3 #count: 200
15:38:55.030 [main] INFO com...DummyManyTests - after all...
```

**How can I achieve this ?**

Comment: There's no way to parametrize class
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182118/junit5-parameterized-tests-at-class-level

Comment: I've done what's suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77008774/1180351 a few times, works pretty well

Comment: Deriving from a superclass or interface is the only supported way to parameterized a full test suite. If that‘s suitable for your case depends on how many variations you have. Half a dozen is probably still reasonable. A few hundred subclasses probably not.

Comment: @RobSpoor that seems to be the closest thing to what I need, at least from what I could find so far...

Comment: @johanneslink if you have that many, or need dynamic parameterization, you can always go for `@TestFactory` and `DynamicContainer`. Whenever I need to do that, I usually create a private method for creating each nested `DynamicContainer` and `DynamicTest` so the code won't become unreadable.

Comment: I could be very wide of the mark here but have you considered Property based testing: https://jessitron.com/2013/04/25/property-based-testing-what-is-it/ or https://medium.com/criteo-engineering/introduction-to-property-based-testing-f5236229d237