# Junit 5 - can I use TestFactory & DynamicTest to generate entire test classes?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I found a partial solution to [my previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826638/junit5-can-i-parameterize-execution-of-entire-test-class).

Now I have the following sample code:

The abstract class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class DummyManyTestsAbstract {

    int count;

    @BeforeAll
    public void beforeAll() {
        System.out.println("Before all...");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public void afterAll() {
        System.out.println("After all...");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(10)
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 #count: " + count);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(20)
    public void m2() {
        System.out.println("m2 #count: " + count);
    }
}
```

And the running class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;

class DummyManyTests {

    @Nested
    public class Dummy50Tests extends DummyManyTestsAbstract {
        public Dummy50Tests() {
            super(50);
        }
    }

    @Nested
    public class Dummy100Tests extends DummyManyTestsAbstract {
        public Dummy100Tests() {
            super(100);
        }
    }
}
```

The tests structure is preserved, everything runs the way I need it.

**The question:** considering that the `@Nested` Test Classes that I run are basically identical (only instantiated with different `count` parameter), could I make use of the `@TestFactory` functionality to dynamically instantiate them, **while still preserving the tests structure** ?

Comment: Why not make both test methods a parameterized test with the same argument source? You could create your own composed annotation, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72783483/6395627), to potentially make it less verbose and more maintainable. Or, if the effort is worth it, you _might_ be able to "parameterize" the class by creating your own [test template](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-test-templates) (though I'm not sure if that's possible/appropriate).

Comment: I need to maintain the structure & testing sequence; first `@BeforeAll` should run, then the test class with 50 items entirely, then `@AfterAll` should run, and only after that should the execution go to the next value of the `count`. Also, I need to have the test results distinct for the `...50Tests`, `...100Tests`, etc...

Comment: Short of writing your own `TestEngine` or switching frameworks, I think your general approach is the best option in JUnit 5. Though I don't believe you're using `@Nested` as intended; see [§2.12 Nested Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested) for an example. It would probably make more sense to have the nested classes as top-level classes that extend `DummyManyTestsAbstract`. Unfortunately, the only way I can think to "automate" this is to create an annotation processor to generate source files at compile-time, which may be more effort than it's worth.